# How to do Salary >= 10000 && Salary <= 20000

Tags: java, junit, operators

So heres my code:

```
public class employee {

    //attributes
    String Name = "name";
    String Position = "position";


    //behavior
    public static char getSalary(int Salary) {
        if (Salary >= 10000 && Salary <= 20000) {
            return 'C';
        } else if (Salary >= 20000 && Salary <= 40000) {
            return 'B';
        } else {
            return 'A';
        }
    }
}
```

when I run a test it gets error because if (Salary >= 10000 && Salary <= 20000) and
(Salary >= 20000 && Salary <= 40000) both have 20000, what should I do?

Comment: What's the error code?
Please, make sure your naming conventions are right.

Comment: Either change Salary < 20000, or Salary > 20000 in other if

Comment: it should only be either 10000-19999 or 20001 - 40000

Comment: First of all: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character, variable names with lower case character

Comment: Please share the code of the test.

Comment: And also share the specification. Should the return value C or B if the salary is exactly 20000

Comment: you need to define what the expected output is if the salary is 20000, then write the code according to that

Answer (score 0):

FOR 20000 below code will always return C. because if first condition is True in IF-ELSE then all other if-else will not be used(try using breakpoint you will understand). Also you need to find out what is your boundary value. like if 20000 mean B, then you should use <20000 for C.